# How has anyone successfully used rostest for automated testing in ROS Melodic and Noetic since 2015?

Tags: ros-melodic, catkin, catkin-make, ubuntu-trusty, rostest

I'm developing for a system currently based on ROS Melodic, running on Ubuntu 18.04. I'm adding unit testing for a node in C++ and thus registering the test with the `add_rostest_gtest` catkin/CMake function.

In setting up this test I found that running it manually via `rostest <pkg> <test>` worked successfully. However running `catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DCATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING=On; make -C build/ run_tests` or `caktin run_tests` results in this test always being reported as a failure due to missing the expected xml output file.

I tracked the cause down to [ros_comm PR 611](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/611) where escaped quotes were added to [ros_comm/tools/rostest/cmake/rosttest-extras.cmake.em:56](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/845f74602c7464e08ef5ac6fd9e26c97d0fe42c9/tools/rostest/cmake/rostest-extras.cmake.em#L56) when creating the rostest command to be run by CMake. On my system this results in the output path for the xml file containing those escaped quotes, and then every check for that file fails because it is not written where it should be written.

If I modify `/opt/ros/melodic/share/rostest/cmake/rostest-extras.cmake` on my installed system to remove those escaped quotes then the tests succeed as expected when run as `catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DCATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING=On; make -C build/ run_tests` or `caktin run_tests`.

In this testing I'm using the default terminal and there is nothing crazy in `.bashrc` or `profile.d/*`. My locale is set as:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

For my own sanity I also was able to reproduce this issue with a trivial minimal working example:

---

`hello_test_world/CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(hello_test_world)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES hello_test_world
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

link_libraries(
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

if(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
    find_package(rostest REQUIRED)
    add_rostest_gtest(test1 src/test_hello.test src/test_hello.cc)

    # Issue is really at the add_rostest level
    add_rostest(src/test_hello2.test DEPENDENCIES test1)
endif()
```

`hello_test_world/package.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>hello_test_world</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>Simple package to demonstrate testing nodes</description>
  <license>MIT</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>std_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
  <test_depend>gtest</test_depend>
</package>
```

`hello_test_world/src/test_hello.cc`

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <ros/ros.h>


TEST(NoComms, JustSucceed)
{
    SUCCEED() << "Just succeeding all day long";
}

TEST(NoComms, AlwaysTrue)
{
    EXPECT_TRUE(true);
}

TEST(Comms, JustSayHello)
{
    ros::NodeHandle nh("~");
    ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<std_msgs::String>("hello", 1, true);
    std_msgs::String str_msg;
    str_msg.data = "hello test world!";
    pub.publish(str_msg);

    ros::spinOnce();

    const ros::Duration d(1.0);
    d.sleep();

    SUCCEED() << "Not even checking if we really sent anything";
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    ros::init(argc, argv, "test_hello");
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

`hello_test_world/src/test_hello.test`

```
<launch>
    <test test-name="hello_tester1" pkg="hello_test_world" type="test1" />
</launch>
```

and `hello_test_world/src/test_hello2.test` is simply a copy of `hello_test_world/src/test_hello.test`.

---

So it seems this should have prevented the entire ROS community from leveraging rostest for automated testing in CI/CD pipelines for the past ~9 years ... but I find that very hard to believe.

How can `rostest` be successfully used as part of an automated testing pipeline?